# c++ state manager- how to create a state?

Tags: c++, state

I used http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118898-state-management/ to set up my states and the manager. Which remained unclear was, how to add states to said system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass `GameState`, i.e.

```
class MainMenuState : public GameState{
public:
  virtual void Init(){
    /* Your init code */
  }
  virtual void Cleanup(){
    /* Your cleanup code */
  }
  virtual void Pause(){
    /* Callback received when state is paused */
  }
  virtual void Resume(){
    /* Callback received when state is resumed */
  }
  virtual void GetEvents(){
    /* get events */
  }
  virtual void Update(){
    /* update */
  }
  virtual void Display(){
    /* display */
  }
};
```

Then you can call your `PushState` function with the new class as argument:

```
MainMenuState menuState;
stateManager.PushState(&menuState);
```